# How to hide This tab is using your camera or microphone opentok

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, opentok

I'm using opentok javascript library for a video calling app. When the video call is ended with a call i am calling

```
session.disconnect(); 
session.destroy();
session.unpublish(publisher);
```

in chrome (at least) the red camera icon is still visible with the message "This tab is using your camera or microphone".

How can I hide this warning red dot icon?. This icon is always visible in my site.

Please help me guys

```
 var publisher = OT.initPublisher(targetElement, publisherProperties, function(error) {
            if (error) {

              if (error.name === 'OT_USER_MEDIA_ACCESS_DENIED') {
                // Access denied can also be handled by the accessDenied event
                videocall_err.innerHTML='Please allow access to the Camera and Microphone and try publishing again.';
              } else {
                videocall_err.innerHTML='Failed to get access to your camera or microphone. Please check that your webcam' + ' is connected and not being used by another application and try again.';
              }
              publisher.destroy();
              publisher = null;

               videocall_err.innerHTML = '';
            } else {
              console.log('Publisher initialized.');
            }
          });
         // publisher = OT.initPublisher('myPublisherDiv', publisherProperties);
          console.log(publisher);
          session.publish(publisher, function(error) {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            } else {
              console.log('Publishing a stream.');
            }
          });
          publisher.on('streamCreated', function (event) {
              console.log('The publisher started streaming.');
          });




 publisher.on("streamDestroyed", function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
    session.disconnect(); 
session.destroy();
session.unpublish(publisher);
                 console.log("The publisher stopped streaming. Reason: "
                  + event.reason);


              });
```

im using  event.preventDefault(); because i want to reuse my publisher

Comment: That would be a bug, those methods should certainly turn the light off. Can you describe your environment such as operating system, microphone/webcam, version of chrome and the full code you use to connect/publish/disconnect? Thanks

Comment: @aiham plz see i have edit my question

Answer (score 1):

You are still seeing the webcam light because you are calling preventDefault() on the publisher's streamDestroyed event.

See: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#.event:streamDestroyed

> The publisher has stopped streaming to the session. The default
>   behavior is that the Publisher object is removed from the HTML DOM.
>   The Publisher object dispatches a destroyed event when the element is
>   removed from the HTML DOM. If you call the preventDefault() method of
>   the event object in the event listener, the default behavior is
>   prevented, and you can, optionally, retain the Publisher for reuse or
>   clean it up using your own code.

You should only call preventDefault() if you intend to reuse this publisher in a future session.